# Inconvertible types when using groupingBy

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have a class

```
class TranslatedWords extends ArrayList<TranslatedWord>
```

I'm trying to group **TranslatedWord** objects by **word** field

```
public Map<String, TranslatedWords> getTranslatedWordsByWord(TranslatedWords translatedWords){
    if (translatedWords == null || translatedWords.isEmpty()){
        return Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
    }
    return (Map<String, TranslatedWords>) translatedWords.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TranslatedWord::getWord, Collectors.toList()));
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<completedTaskFour.TranslatedWord>>' to 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,completedTaskFour.TranslatedWords>'

But my class extends ArrayList, why am I getting this error? And what can I do to make the output argument be a Map<String, TranslatedWords>?

Comment: Grouping must result in `Map<String, List<TranslatedWords>>` unless you explicitly reduce values to a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Using collector with the supplier of custom collection should work:

```java
public Map<String, TranslatedWords> getTranslatedWordsByWord(TranslatedWords translatedWords){
    if (translatedWords == null || translatedWords.isEmpty()){
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    return translatedWords
        .stream() // Stream<TranslatedWord>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            TranslatedWord::getWord, 
            Collectors.toCollection(TranslatedWords::new)
        ));
}
```